# Is is possible to get $\gcd(b, c)$ from $\gcd(a, b, c)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

$\gcd(a,b,c) = \gcd(a, \gcd(b, c))$, but is it possible to get $\gcd(b, c)$ from $\gcd(a, b, c)$?

Give a list of numbers, I want to efficiently compute the $\gcd$ of any slice of numbers from that list. A slice is a contiguous section of the list -- e.g. say from the third element to the tenth element. Say the list is $[a, b, c, d, e, ...]$. I was wondering if by precomputing $\gcd(a, b)$, $\gcd(a, b, c)$, $\gcd(a, b, c, d)$, $\gcd(a, b, c, d, e)$, etc. I can efficiently extract say $\gcd(c, d, e)$ (the $\gcd$ fo the slice from the third element to the fifth element) from $\gcd(a, b, c, d, e)$.

Comment: Any two sequences starting with $a = 1$ will lead to the same sequence $\gcd(a, b), \gcd(a, b, c), \gcd(a, b, c, d), \dots = 1, 1, 1, \dots$, so I guess that doesn't quite work.

Comment: If you factor the elements of the list into primes, the problem becomes finding, for each prime, the minimum of its exponents on each slice. I think there are algorithms that could accomplish that fairly quickly.

Comment: You could also store a tree of gcds initially, with each node containing gcds of nodes below it and leaves being the array elements.  Once calculated and stored, reading off the answer you need  is easy. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree for more.

Comment: @Macavity Storing the gcds at the nodes of a tree will work very well because the binary gcd() operation is associative. Once the tree is stored, a logarithmic number of gcd computations are sufficient to compute the gcd of any slice. Generic code can be used that handles any associative operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea will not work.
We have $\gcd(6,10)=2$, $\gcd(6,10,15)=1$, and $\gcd(10,15)=5$.
On the other hand, we have $\gcd(6,10)=2$, $\gcd(6,10,7)=1$, and $\gcd(10,7)=1$.
If there were to be such a function $f$ satisfying $f(\gcd(a,b),\gcd(a,b,c))=\gcd(a,b,c)$
for all $a,b,c$,
then we would have $1=f(2,1)=5$,
impossible.

One proposal by @Macavity and @Gribouillis in the comments is to store the gcd of some slices in a segment tree.
Here's an [example](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html#simplest-form-of-a-segment-tree) demonstrating how to use a segment tree for sum of slices.

For notational simplicity, use $[a,b]$ to represent the gcd of the slice from index $a$ and index $b$, inclusive.
Use $s_1*s_2$ to represent $\gcd(s_1,s_2)$.The gcd of a single number is defined to be itself.
It is not hard to verify that $[a,b]*[c,d]=[a,d]$.

To illustrate, suppose $n=5$ is the size of the array.
Suppose we have constructed and stored the values of $[0,1],[0,2],[3,4],[0,4]$ and of course $[a,a]$ for any $0\le a<5$.
Then, for example,
$$
\begin{align*}
[2,4] &= [2,2]*[3,4] \\
[1,4] &= [1,1]*[2,2]*[3,4] \\
[0,3] &= [0,2]*[3,3]
\end{align*}
$$
We can compute the gcd of any slice in $O(\log n)$ time.

---

By the way, finding the prime factorization of each number in the array, suggested by @Alma Arjuna, is certainly slower than the segment tree in most cases.
Assuming integer division is $O(1)$,
the time complexity of factorization of a number $a$ is $O(\sqrt{a})$,
but that of taking gcd of $a$ and $b$ is $O(\log(a)+\log(b))$.